# Case-insensitive Glob on zsh/bash

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, glob

I need to list all files whose names start with 'SomeLongString'. But the case of 'SomeLongString' can vary. How?

I am using zsh, but a bash solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

ZSH:

```
$ unsetopt CASE_GLOB
```

Or, if you don't want to enable case-insensitive globbing in general, you can activate it for only the varying part:

```
$ print -l (#i)(somelongstring)*
```

This will match any file that starts with "somelongstring" (in any combination of lower/upper case). The case-insensitive flag applies for everything between the parentheses and can be used multiple times. Read the manual `zshexpn(1)` for more information.

**UPDATE**
Almost forgot, you have to enable extendend globbing for this to work:

```
setopt extendedglob
```

Comment: What about `setopt no_CASE_GLOB`?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you have `nocaseglob` set, then you can use `(#I)` to temporarily undo it, for a case-sensitive glob.

Answer (score 41):

bash:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a way to specify it as part of the glob itself. The zsh manual mentions something like it but I was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 17):

Depending on how deep you want to have this listing, `find` offers quite a lot
in this regard:

```
find . -iname 'SomeLongString*' -maxdepth 1
```

This will only give you the files in the current directory. Important here is
the `-iname` parameter instead of `-name`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ function i () {
> shopt -s nocaseglob; $*; shopt -u nocaseglob
> }
$ ls *jtweet*
ls: cannot access *jtweet*: No such file or directory
$ i ls *jtweet*
JTweet.pm  JTweet.pm~  JTweet2.pm  JTweet2.pm~
```

Comment: **You need to quote the glob to pass it to the function safely**.  If `*jtweet*` matches anything, it will be expanded before the function sees it.  (Or error or empty string depending on other `shopt` settings).  Interesting idea, though.  I think it will mostly work if you run `i ls '*jtweet*'`, even if there's also a `jtweet.pm in the directory.  There are lots of potential problems with spaces or other special characters in non-glob args, or in the glob, though.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness (and frankly surprised it's not mentioned yet, even though all the other answers are better and/or "more correct"), obviously one can also use (especially for `grep` aficionados):

```
$ ls | egrep -i '^SomeLongString'
```

One might also stick in a redundant `ls -1` (that's option "one", not "ell"), but when passed to a pipe, each entry is already going to be one per line, anyway. I'd typically use something like this (vs `set`) in shell scripts, eg in a `for`/`while` loop: `for i in $(ls | grep -i ...)` . However, the other answer using `find` would be preferable & more flexible in that circumstance, because you can, for example, omit directories (or set other restrictions): `for i in $(find . -type f -iname 'SomeString*' -print -maxdepth 1)...` or even forgo the loop altogether and just use the power of `find` all by itself, eg: `find ... -exec do_stuff {} \; ...` , but I do digress (again, for completeness.)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a long, full solution (creating thumbnails from a list of camera images):

```bash
_shopt="$( shopt -p )"
shopt -s nocaseglob
for f in *.jpg; do
    convert "$f" -auto-orient -resize "1280x1280>" -sharpen 8 jpeg:"$( basename "$f" ".${f##*.}" ).shelf.jpg"
done
eval "$_shopt"
```

Since we don't know exact extension case (.jpg or .JPG), we create it from the name itself by stripping the prefix up to (and including) the last dot.
The -auto-orient option will take care of image orientation so that thumbnails would be viewed correctly on any device.

Comment: For zsh change `shopt` to `setopt`.