# Case-Insensitive ZSH Suffix Aliases

Tags: linux, unix, shell, zsh

In my .zshrc I've set up suffix completion aliases like this so that I can open files more easily:

```
alias -s -- txt='mate -w'
```

Which allows me to open text files in my text editor without prepending the editor command.

There is a problem, however, when I am attempting to open a file with a capitalized suffix. ZSH will recognize '.txt' and open it in my text editor but not '.TXT.'

Is there any way to make ZSH suffix recognition case-insensitive so that I can open files like these?

Comment: hm, even nocaseglob is ignored with alias -s

Answer (score 5):

Let me hazard a guess :)

```
alias -s -- TXT='mate -w'
alias -s -- Txt='mate -w'
alias -s -- TXt='mate -w'
alias -s -- tXt='mate -w'
alias -s -- txT='mate -w'
alias -s -- tXT='mate -w'
alias -s -- TxT='mate -w'
```

Comment: This seems to be the extrapolated version of my single line answer. By interpolation of combinatorics via the shell, I'm able to get the equivalent of your's by doing this: `alias -s {t,T}{x,X}{t,T}=cat`.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to fix it for me:

```
setopt extendedglob
unsetopt CASE_GLOB
```

I got the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156916/case-insensitive-glob-on-zsh-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the suffix aliases once in lower case and redefine them with the extensions programmatically converted to uppercase:

```
for ext in ${(k)saliases}; alias -s $ext:u=$saliases[$ext]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the extrapolation of t and T, x and X, and finally t and T. This is really just simplistic combinatorics code, an then assigns that `cat`.

`alias -s {t,T}{x,X}{t,T}=cat`

If you run something like `echo {t,T}{x,X}{t,T}` you can see that I'm just interpolating `ttt ttT tTt tTT Ttt TtT TTt TTT` in to the alias.